# Unwated additional row in Telerik hierarchical grid

Tags: vb.net, telerik, telerik-grid

I've got a normal Telerik hierarchical grid with a child detail table. However when the items get bound in the master table there is an extra row between each item. It has a cell with the class "rgExpandCol". I suppose this has to do with the expand icon? I have run out of ideas...

Has anyone out there experienced this before?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a [similar post in Telerik Forums](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/hide-disable-expand-column.aspx), trying to hide this Expand column.

Here is the trick, add the following CSS in your page:

```
 <style type="text/css"> 
        .rgExpandCol 
        { 
            display:none !important; 
        } 
 </style>
```

If it doesn't work, try this in the PreRender event:

```
protected void RadGrid1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
        RadGrid1.MasterTableView.ExpandCollapseColumn.Display = false; 
    }
```

If those 2 don't work, there is an extra one a little bit more complicated in the Telerik post about the PreRenderEvent.

Comment: It works but I need the expand column there to expand my grid :)

Comment: @The_Butcher : You wonder if it is because of the icons, do you have any problem with them ? If you start a new project and build a simple hierarchical table, do you have the same problem ? It is to know if it has something to do with your current project or if the grid behaviour is always the same.

Comment: I basically copied the code from an existing hierarchical grid and changed two of the column names. Nothing additional was added. Also the original grid does'nt have any custom css etc.. The only css is used from the embedded stylesheet inside the telerik dll :/

Comment: ended up being an issue of the hierarchical grid being inside a tab-strip. stange...

Answer (score 0):

This is an odd one - is there any client or server code you have which manipulates the items in the master table somehow? Debug your code and compare it with the rendered html to get more clues.